# Return a CGAffineTransform from a function

Tags: ios, objective-c, struct, core-animation, quartz-graphics

I have a instance method that I'd like to return a CGAffineTransform.  I'm currently getting the error

```
Semantic Issue: Initializing 'CGAffineTransform' (aka 'struct CGAffineTransform') with an expression of incompatible type 'id'
```

My method name

```
- (CGAffineTransform)getEllipse
```

My call to it

```
CGAffineTransform t = [self getEllipse];
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure that the method is declared somewhere visible to the code that calls it? I.e., if:

```
- (CGAffineTransform)getEllipse;
```

is in MyFoo.h, and MyBar.m contains:

```
CGAffineTransform t = [self getEllipse];
```

then MyBar.m needs to `#import "MyFoo.h"`. Without being able to see the declaration, the calling code will assume that the method returns an object of unknown type, a.k.a. `id`.

Comment: Ha, that worked.  I'm just writing some test code so I didn't worry about defining my methods in my header file.  I know that you don't have to declare each method in the header.  Is this only an issue sinc its not returning an object.  I even tried casting the return value in my call - but I'm not exactly sure if you can cast with a struct.  Any clarification would be great.

Comment: @Brian: The compiler assumes return type of `id` if it gets to the method definition without having seen a prior declaration. (There may be more to it than that -- I'm not an expert.) You can't cast structs, no. See this SO question for some details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752989/how-to-cast-c-struct-just-another-struct-type-if-their-memory-size-are-equal